# How to store jQuery output into global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

See Code below -

```
 $(function() {
  $.fn.getPosition = function() {
    var results = $(this).position();
    results.right = results.left + $(this).width();
    results.bottom = results.top + $(this).height();
    return results;
  }

  $(".drag").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      console.log($(this).attr("id"), $(this).getPosition());
    }
  });
});
```

Excuse the noob question but how do i store the output of `.getPosition()` into a global vairable that i can use in other functions instead of  `console.log($(this).attr("id"), $(this).getPosition());`.

Comment: decalre a variable at the top of the js file and assign the position to that variable. `var position =""; `inside the draggable function, `position = $(this).getPosition();`

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new variable in the global scope. Then use it in other methods as well.

Updated in the below code snippet:

```
 let positionValue;
 $(function() {
  $.fn.getPosition = function() {
    var results = $(this).position();
    results.right = results.left + $(this).width();
    results.bottom = results.top + $(this).height();
    return results;
  }

  $(".drag").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      positionValue = $(this).attr("id"), $(this).getPosition();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: tried this before says undefined when i call it in another function

Comment: It will be initialised only when the event is triggered since it's provided in the callback function of that particular event. I think, here it is on drag-stop event. If you want a default value, you can initialise it on the variable declaration itself. `let positionValue = some value;`

Answer (score 0):

You can first declare a global variable on the top of your file. (as told in the comment below your post)

```
 let position;
 $(function() {
 $.fn.getPosition = function() {
     var results = $(this).position();
     results.right = results.left + $(this).width();
     results.bottom = results.top + $(this).height();
     return results;
 }

 $(".drag").draggable({
     containment: "parent",
     stop: function(e, ui) {
         position = $(this).getPosition();
         console.log($(this).attr("id"), $(this).getPosition());
     }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a global variable before, and use it where you want the assignment to take place:

```
var yourVariable; // <-- declare here

$(function() {
  $.fn.getPosition = function() {
    var results = $(this).position();
    results.right = results.left + $(this).width();
    results.bottom = results.top + $(this).height();
    return results;
  }

  $(".drag").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      console.log($(this).attr("id"), $(this).getPosition());
      yourVariable = $(this).getPosition();     // <-- assign here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: tried this before says undefined when i call it in another function\